# How can I interact multiple objects with dependency injection?

Tags: php, oop, dependency-injection, abstract-class

giving this code:

## Animal.php

```
abstract class Animal {
private $name;
private $health;

public function getHealth(){
    return $this->health;  
}

public function hurt(){

}

public function setHealth($health){
    $this->health = $health;

}
}
```

## Wolf.php

```
class Wolf extends Animal{
    public function hurt(Tiger $tiger) {
        $tiger->setHealth(80);

    }
```

## index.php

```
class StackOverflowExample{
        public static function run(){

            $dog = new Dog("Cokey",100);
            $wolf = new Wolf("Wolfenstein",100);
            $tiger = new Tiger("Rocky",100);

            $wolf->hurt($tiger);
            echo $tiger->getHealth();

            $wolf->hurt($dog);
            echo $dog->getHealth();
        }
    }
    StackOverflowExample::run();
```

I have the problem that the Wolf can hurt Tiger because his code, but I can't hurt the dog because I need to specify only one Class and Object on the arguments. Are there any way for interact with both classes, tiger and dog?
Here is the error:

```
Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to Wolf::hurt() must be an instance of Tiger, instance of Dog given
```

Thanks

Comment: I'm not very familiar with PHP, but I'm not seeing any dependency injection here unless it's just very different from what i would expect.  You could have hurt take in a type animal instead of type tiger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should remove the type hint in your function if you don't want to restrict the parameter to a single class.

Here is an example using the [get_class()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-class.php) function to retrieve the name of the `$animal`'s class to achieve the desired effect:

```
class Wolf extends Animal{
    public function hurt($animal) {
        // If animal is a tiger.
        if (get_class($animal) === 'Tiger') {
            $animal->setHealth(80);
        }
        // If animal is a dog.
        if (get_class($animal) === 'Dog') {
            $animal->setHealth(50);
        }
}
```

Comment: I can't create multiple instances from different classes with the same name, in your case $animal.

Comment: @Schwarzenegger I created a quick gist of what I understand from your code. I also give the output of the program. https://gist.github.com/edmundluong/b3e80e6fd772614b1610